# bypass exit in code in Tcl

Tags: tcl, exit

let us assume that I have proc foo. The proc code is:

```
proc foo { argy } {
   if { $argy == 1 } { exit 1 }
}
```

I want to call foo, but have the calling code bypass/ignore the exit command, and not exit TCL. I.e.: this code:

```
foo 1
puts "bar"
```

Should yield:

```
>bar
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: If Dinesh's answer solves your problem, consider accepting the answer to indicate to other readers that it was useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rename` to override the default behaviour.

```
rename exit _exit
proc exit {{status ""}} {}
```

Keep the above code, before the first occurrence of exit command in your code. i.e. even at the start of your code, so that the `exit` will be replaced with this dummy `exit` procedure.

Comment: Maybe make the fake `exit` do `return`?

Comment: @DonalFellows : Since OP simply want to bypass the `exit`, I made the empty definition, thereby making it to have no meaning at all. Perhaps, `return` can be added if necessary.

Comment: The body of the new `exit` proc would be `return -code return` so that it behaves just like a `return` command

Comment: I am sorry for not this question, but what does {status ""} do?
I have never seen such a code style...

Comment: It's a default argument. Status is the first argument band and emit th string is the default value.

Comment: @user1134991 : Have a look at [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl12.html)